# Kubernetes install TimescaleDB

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, timescaledb

I'm trying to install in my Kubernetes cluster [TimescaleDB](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb), unfortunately following more tutorials I always fall in a similar error.

For example, I tried [this tutorial](https://praveenperera.com/blog/install-timescale-2-0-on-kubernetes) but the pod 'timescale-db-timescaledb-data-1' has the error:

```
install: cannot change owner and permissions of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata’: No such file or directory
install: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata’: Permission denied
```

I also tried to install it from the Lens Charts repository, but nothing works.

PS: I need to have 3 nodes in my cluster (minikube on Linux)

Comment: Please add more information about you Kubernetes cluster, version, how deployed. It seems the problem related to Postgres permissions and volume mounting: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/361 https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/213 Did you try something to resolve it?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin I update the question, minikube on linux... that link doesn't help me

Comment: The TimescaleDB helm charts may give you a good starting point... Did you find these? https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-kubernetes

Comment: @greenweeds yes I tried, unfortunately it doesn't work